# Shortest equivalent word for FPG

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a finitely presented group $G$ and a word $w$ in $G$, is there always an efficient algorithm to find the set of shortest words equivalent to $w$?

I am guessing that the problem of finding the shortest words is undecideable if the group is infinite, but possibly efficient if the group is finite.

Comment: Of course there are algorithms that work when $G$ is finite, but it is a challenging problem for large finite groups. Think of the Rubik Cube group. There are also arbitrarily difficult presentations of very small groups, which makes the problem challenging for a different reason.

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574874/shortest-words-in-a-group-with-finite-presentation?rq=1).

Comment: It's definitely not decidable for any finitely presented group. We know that equality of words is undecidable for some finitely presented groups. And $w = x$ if and only if the shortest word representing $w^{-1} x$ is $e$ (the empty sequence of words). So we can reduce word equality to this problem; hence, this problem is undecidable (and possibly not semi-decidable)

Answer (score 2):

The [*word problem*](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Word_problems/) for a group $G$ given by a finite presentation $\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ is the problem of determining whether a word $W\in(\mathbf{x}^{\pm1})^*$, i.e. a word over the generators $\mathbf{x}$ and their formal inverses, defines the trivial element of $G$. This problem is undecidable in general.

**Theorem.**
Fix a group $G=\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$.
There exists an algorithm with input a word $W\in(\mathbf{x}^{\pm1})^*$ and output the set of shortest words equivalent to $W$ if and only if $G$ has decidable word problem.

*Proof.*
The word problem in $G=\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ reduces to the problem here, as a word defines the trivial element if and only if the set of shortest words equivalent to $W$ is precisely $\{\epsilon\}$ (here $\epsilon$ denotes the empty word, the unique word of length $0$). Hence, there is no algorithm to solve your problem in groups with undecidable word problem.

Suppose on the other hand that $G=\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ has decidable word problem. Then enumerate all words $U\in(\mathbf{x}^{\pm1})^*$ such that $|U|\leq|W|$. By applying the word problem to $U^{-1}W$, we can find all such words which are additionally equal to $W$ in $G$. Hence, we have found the set $\mathcal{S}$ of all words $U$ which are no longer than $W$ and which are equal to $W$ in $G$. The set we are seeking is the set of shortest elements in $\mathcal{S}$, which is now easily computable. QED

---

In particular, there are infinite groups where this problem can be solved (e.g. finitely generated abelian groups and free groups).